# Решение задачи на Python по комбинаторике

Tags: python

[image]
Приветствую товарищи знатоки! Есть такая вот задача, которую нужно реализовать на Python. Как я понял, она на комбинаторику

Пробовал разными способами, но в итоге ничего не получилось

Comment: кому нужно, тот и реализует. Обычно так. Ну или показывай свои разные способы.

Comment: Покажите хотя бы один ваш неудачный код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ради интереса решил задачку, код получился такой:

```
from math import factorial

n, m, k = (int(i) for i in input().split())


def C(k,n):
    assert k <= n
    return factorial(n)/( factorial(n-k) * factorial(k) )

answer = C(1, n) * m * C(2, k) + n * C(2, m) * k + C(2, n) * m * k
print(int(answer))
```

Но это действительно не совсем тот форум, чтобы просто закидывать задачки. Хоть бы ссылку прикрепили.
UPD
Спасибо @MBo за то что подсказал более простой способ

Answer (score 1):

```
Цеизкаподванаэмнаэн плюс 
цеизэмподванаканаэн плюс 
цеизэнподванаканаэм
```